# Blazor Server error aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:56871/' failed

Tags: blazor, refresh, blazor-server-side

Running a Blazor Server app is showing a partially rendered page with a browser console error of:

```
aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:234 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:56871/' failed
```

It would appear that no recent changes have been made to the code. There doesn't seem to be any code issues, how can I go about isolating this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

This issue has now been fixed in v17.1.5. You would want to update to this version.

Reference to release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#17.1.5

Original Answer to rollback install:

It appears that this is a bug in Visual Studio v17.1.1. If I revert back to v17.0 then the application launches successfully.

FIX:

1. Uninstall Visual Studio v17.1.1 (via VS Installer)
2. Install specific version v17.0.7 package from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history

Reference to the bug (a report indicates it is also present in 17.1.2):
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/WebSocket-connection-to-wss:-fail/1670519?q=ERR_CONNECTION_RESET&ftype=problem&space=8&stateGroup=active&sort=newest

Answer (score 1):

installing preview version 17.2 also solves this problem

Comment: Upgrading to Update version: 17.2.0 Preview 2.1 resolved the error for me. thx.